# Downloading a file using Dart GDrive api with authorized GET request

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm coding in Dart and need to download a file (i.e. an image file) from google GDrive using OAuth2.0. I am at the point in my code where I have the downloadURL after having used the Dart drive_v2_api_browser client library.

I tried directly passing this to the "*src*" attribute

```dart
_image = new ImageElement(src: file.downloadUrl, width: file.imageMediaMetadata.width, height: file.imageMediaMetadata.height);
_image.onLoad.listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: true);
```

but that yielded a 403 forbidden error. That's when I realized I need to make an "*authorized **GET** request*". So I tried following the example listed on the Dart Auth pub package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_oauth2_client, but I don't understand what it asking for.

This is what I am trying:

```dart
var auth = new oauth.SimpleOAuth2(_picker.Token.data);
var request = new HttpRequest();
request.onLoad.listen(onData_Request, onError: onError_Request, onDone: onDone_Request, cancelOnError: true);
request.open("request", file.downloadUrl);
auth.authenticate(request).then((request) => request.send());
```

but it keeps giving me an error:

token.... *Method request is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.*

Does anyone have a working example of downloading a file through the Dart GDrive api relative to OAuth2.0?

**Update**: After Günter Zöchbauer help I was able to continue and convert the blob as such:

Adding this line to the request object:

```dart
_downloadRequest.responseType = "blob";
```

Allowed me to use a file reader:

```dart
void onData_Request(Event e) {
  Blob response = _downloadRequest.response;
  final FileReader reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onLoad.listen((e) {
        _handleData(reader);
      });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(response);
}

void _handleData(FileReader reader) {
  Uint8List uintlist = new Uint8List.fromList(reader.result);
  String charcodes = new String.fromCharCodes(uintlist);
  _loadImage(_image, charcodes, 225, 225);
}

void _loadImage(ImageElement imageE, String data, int iWidth, int iHeight) {
  _imageAsbase64 = window.btoa(data);

 _image = new ImageElement(src: "data:image/png;base64," + _imageAsbase64, width: iWidth, height: iHeight);
 _image.onLoad.listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: true);
}

void onData(Event e) {
  print("success: ");
  _context.drawImage(_image, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says `request` is not a valid HTTP method.
You need something like `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`, ...

see also http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Okay. I was getting the "request" from the Dart documentation. It also listed three others. I just wasn't sure what to put there as my understanding of this area is limited.

Comment: Did you make progress with a concrete method like "GET"?

Comment: That worked Günter Zöchbauer. Using *GET* fixed the error. I was then able to convert the blob being returned and display the image: