# Dart Html - Convert Blob to File

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm attempting to write a test for some dart:html code.

I have a method with a File parameter (html File, not io File).

```
testFile(File file)
```

I'm able to create a Blob with the needed data for the file (minus file name, date, etc.), but it appears there is no way to create File objects in dart:html, as it's reserved for internal use in html_dartium.dart.

```
factory File._() { throw new UnsupportedError("Not supported"); }
```

Is there any other way to create an HTML File object?

I've seen FileReaders mentioned, but the results from those is either a String or uint8list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research, I achieved what I was looking for with the following:

```
  List<String> file_contents = ["test\n"];
  Blob blob = new Blob(file_contents, 'text/plain', 'native');

  FileSystem _filesystem = await window.requestFileSystem(1024 * 1024, persistent: false);
  FileEntry fileEntry = await _filesystem.root.createFile('dart_test.csv');
  FileWriter fw = await fileEntry.createWriter();
  fw.write(blob);
  File file = await fileEntry.file();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
  Blob response = _downloadRequest.response;
  final FileReader reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onLoad.listen((e) {
        _handleData(reader);
      });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(response);
```

See [Downloading a file using Dart GDrive api with authorized GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22889356/217408)

Comment: While this may work as well, after some further research, I achieved what I was looking for with my answer.